# Paginated jQuery results from XML file

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, pagination

I am having a spot of trouble trying to paginate some results from an XML file via jQuery, basically I need to display 10 Magazine covers and when the user either click previous or next another 10 are shown, respective of what has been clicked. Here is my code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "issues.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {

                var startIndex = 0; // gets edited via ui
                var howMany = 10; // constant of how many per page, but you could make this a ui changeable thing too
                var $issues = $(xml).find('issue'); //the resulting issues from the xml
                var totalIssues = $issues.length;
    var numPages = Math.ceil(totalIssues / howMany)

    $('span.issuecount').html(+totalIssues+'&nbsp;Issues - '+numPages+'&nbsp;Pages');

                var displayIssues = function() { // display the issues
                      var $issuesPaginated = $issues.slice( startIndex , ($issues.length - startIndex) + howMany );
                      $('#shelf-items li').fadeOut(500); // clear old issues
                      $issuesPaginated.each(function(){
                          var id = $(this).attr('id');
                          var date = $(this).find('date').text();
                          var cover = $(this).find('cover').text();
                          var issue = $(this).find('issuenumber').text();
                          var url = $(this).find('url').text();
                          $('<li id="'+id+'"></li>').html('<a href="'+url+'"><img src="images/covers/'+cover+'" alt="" /></a><br />'+date+' - #'+issue+'').fadeIn(500).appendTo('#shelf-items');
                      });
                }

                $('#prevIssueButton').click(function() {
                    if( startIndex < howMany) {
                        startIndex -= howMany;
                        displayIssues().fadeIn(500);
                    }else {
                        alert('No more previous issues'); // probably want to do something more elegant here, like start over at 0, etc..
                    }
                });
                $('#nextIssueButton').click(function() {
      if( startIndex + howMany >= totalIssues) {
                        startIndex += howMany;
                        displayIssues();
                    }else {
                        alert('No more next issues'); // probably want to do something more elegant here, like start over at 0, etc..
                    }
                });
                displayIssues().fadeIn(500); // display for the first time (ajax call);
            }
   }); // end ajax call

}); // end document-ready
```

edit: there is now also a Javascript error on displayIssues().fadeIn(500);

Answer (score 1):

```
  $(xml).find('issue').each(function(){
```

can become: (using [.slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)  )

```
  var startIndex = 0; //edit this via your ui
  var howMany = 10; 
  var $issues = $(xml).find('issue');
  var $issuesPaginated = $issues.slice( startIndex , ($issues.length - startIndex) + howMany );
  $issuesPaginated.each(function(){
```

Are you using anything server-side? Could you facilitate pagination that way so you aren't loading all that data into the DOM?

for the requested help regarding click handlers:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "issues.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {

                var startIndex = 0; // gets edited via ui
                var howMany = 10; // constant of how many per page, but you could make this a ui changeable thing too
                var $issues = $(xml).find('issue'); //the resulting issues from the xml
                var totalIssues = $issues.length;

                var displayIssues = function() { // display the issues
                      var $issuesPaginated = $issues.slice( startIndex , ($issues.length - startIndex) + howMany );
                      $('#shelf-items').html(''); // clear old issues
                      $issuesPaginated.each(function(){
                          var id = $(this).attr('id');
                          var date = $(this).find('date').text();
                          var cover = $(this).find('cover').text();
                          var issue = $(this).find('issuenumber').text();
                          var url = $(this).find('url').text();
                          $('<li id="'+id+'"></li>').html('<a href="'+url+'"><img src="images/covers/'+cover+'" alt="" /></a><br />'+date+' - #'+issue+'').appendTo('#shelf-items');
                      });
                }

                $('#prevIssueButton').click(function() {
                    if( startIndex < howMany) {
                        startIndex -= howMany;
                        displayIssues();
                    }else {
                        alert('No more previous issues'); // probably want to do something more elegant here, like start over at 0, etc..
                    }
                });
                $('#nextIssueButton').click(function() {
                    if( startIndex + howMany >= totalIssues) {
                        startIndex += howMany;
                        displayIssues();
                    }else {
                        alert('No more next issues'); // probably want to do something more elegant here, like start over at 0, etc..
                    }
                });
                displayIssues(); // display for the first time (ajax call);
            }
   }); // end ajax call

}); // end document-ready
```

Comment: Hi Dan, unfortunatly that hasnt worked. It now shows up blank, also how can I control the pages with the next / previous links?

Comment: yeah, made a quick edit - it the splice method needed to become a jquery object again. But better yet, I used the `.slice()` method and put the math in for you

Comment: There is only going to be a small amount of data contained in the XML file, this is not for public viewing, strictly for private clients - so the DOM load is irrelevant.

That works brilliantly Dan, your help is much appreciated! I just need to know how I can attatch Prev+Next page actions to those buttons I have setup?

Comment: I would make your startIndex, resulting $issues and the total $issues in a variable inside of `$(document).ready()` but outside of the ajax call. Then still inside `$(document).ready()`, you can bind your click events to the prev/next buttons and change your startIndex, redisplay the elements, limit based off of the total elements (e.g. disabled the next button when at the end)..

Comment: Sorry Dan, bit of jQuery noob as you can probably tell, I have no idea to write out those variables, I will be able to do the click functions, could you help me out? Please? :)

Comment: a bit of a crude example, but hopefully this gets you going in the right direction (see answer)

Comment: See updated example, the previous button goes to the back of the results from page 1, but the next button does not work? This has baffled me also when i change the conditonal for next to startIndex + howMany <= totalIssues - it loads page 2 but not 3 :/

Answer (score 0):

I usually deal with large datasets spanning multiple pages, so I include index parameters to my AJAX call. (Which also requires something smart on the server side...) In you case it looks like you're calling a static xml file, in which case I'd ditch the AJAX or have the AJAX dump the results into a variable which you can iterate over at your leisure and under your control.